# Botman conversation cache time not working

Tags: php, laravel, botman

BotMan Version: 2.6

PHP Version: 7.3.23

Laravel Version : 7.16.1

Cache Driver: LaravelCache

i'm using [botman](https://botman.io/) for telegram bot.
everything is ok with botman just the conversation cache time is not working.
this is my botman Configuration code :

```php
use BotMan\BotMan\Cache\LaravelCache;
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;

$config = [
    // Your driver-specific configuration
    "botman" => [
        'conversation_cache_time' => 720 ,
        'user_cache_time' => 720,
    ],
    "telegram" => [
        "token" => env('TELEGRAM_TOKEN'),
    ]
];
// Load the driver(s) you want to use
DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Telegram\TelegramDriver::class);

// Create an instance
$botman = BotManFactory::create($config, new LaravelCache());

//  and other hears , fallback and conversations functions ...
```

every thing about the bot and conversations is fine , but the problem is about the conversation cash time
base on the [conversation document](https://botman.io/2.0/conversations) we have to use drive cache to use conversations and the driver i'm using is laravelCache but i set `conversation_cache_time` to 720 minute but it just takes the default 30 minute.

what should i do?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these lines in their github:

https://github.com/botman/botman/blob/79310f6e6464436aaa2d0522267b2ca00a07fda5/tests/BotManConversationTest.php#L79-L83

https://github.com/botman/botman/blob/4ec6e3f30d620cbcb73a0cf8e1dbf6b34e47f75d/src/Traits/HandlesConversations.php#L47

https://github.com/botman/botman/blob/203e7f5ef68473dd4d71ca7ee31275eae9a92745/src/BotMan.php#L238-L239

It must be like these:

```php
$config = [
    'user_cache_time' => 720,

    'config' => [
        'conversation_cache_time' => 720 ,
    ],

    // Your driver-specific configuration
    "telegram" => [
        "token" => env('TELEGRAM_TOKEN'),
    ]
];
```

and it works.